# Is there any way to merge between Dialogflow agents? Or at least export intents from one agent to another?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assist-api

I've tried documentation and other sources, but I couldn't figure it out 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [export](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-settings#export) one agent into a .zip file through the agent settings. After that you are able to import the intents and entities from the first agent into another agent in the settings of your Dialogflow project.

You have two options when importing the zip of an agent into your dialogflow project

**Restore from ZIP**: Overwrites the current agent with the supplied zip file.

**Import from ZIP**: Adds intents and entities to the current agent from the supplied zip file. If any existing intents or enties have the same name as those in the zip file, they will be replaced.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible and relatively straightforward. You have to Export one agent and Import it into your other agent. For Import/Export details refer to the documentation in here [Import/Export](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-settings)